# javaScript function lagging by one cycle, and getting NaN

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time, base-60

I’ve been away from writing code I have been busy, but I have not stopped working on my program. Its a lot of code so I made it into a codePen. Here is the link:

https://c*depen.io/animalZero/pen/jaerjQ

I know it says you have to enter code that accompanies codepen (redundant) but the javascript alone is 330 HTML and CSS are also hundreds of lines would I have to hit space bar 4 times each line?  ugh technicalities.

I have gotten most of the bugs out of it by now (i’ve been coding since maybe August in JS I work in the trades). I really enjoy the algorithm scripting part of JS the most, and my program does that.

The problem I am having here is that the actualHoursF() function is supposed to tally up the simulated hours and give you a value in the simActual box. I think I’m doing something stupid. When you click the “calculate” button, it populates the simulated totals, but I have multiple event listeners on that button, and actualHoursF() is one of them. If you click the button again, the actualHoursF() function adds the sim totals up, but by then my other functions are poulating the table with new data that doesn’t match what the actualHours total is. It lags behind by one cycle. If someone could help me I’d be really happy.

The other problem is I’m getting NaN sometimes in my sim totals. I notice it only happens when newEndTime() produces a positive integer. newEndTime basically takes the end time that is entered in endTimeEntry and randomly adds or subtracts a number between 0 and 3 to it, giving a simulated time. I also should mention that newStartTime does the same thing for the startTimeEntry. my “cleanUpXXX” functions are there to go from base 10 math and convert into base 60 math by subtracting 40 in certain conditions, and leaving it alone in other conditions. There is 4 of those, two for the manually entered times and two for the simulated times that it comes up with. Also there is a function all the way at the bottom called “newSimStart” and what that does is it starts at line 2, and overwrites the simulated start time with the end time from the previous iteration (pretty cool huh :slight_smile:) This makes it more realistic. Thanks ahead of time guys I know its a lot of code and its not written very well. Also I have some dumb variable names I know I shouldn’t do this but I was being lazy. Thanks!!

PS I can provide more information as necessary.  I posted this on free code camp, but this thread was buried by the mods by attaching it to a two month old dead thread so I am coming to you guys for help.

Comment: When the site told you you couldn't post a link to codepen without posting code, the right thing to do **was not** to bypass that message by putting nonsense in your question. It was to **do what it said**: Put the code in your question, following the guidelines here: [mcve]. (No, seriously, go back and read the linked page.) Also strongly recommend being more concise in your description of the problem if possible.

Comment: Instead of adding a bunch of separate functions as independent handlers to a button, why not add one function as the handler which calls the other functions in the correct order.

Comment: Your JS being 326 lines long should've been a sign in itself. I don't really understand why so much of it is being repeated. What's with all the `Math.random()` stuff? I reckon this could be squished down to maybe 40 lines of code. Perhaps less

Comment: But yes, you definitely don't want multiple event listeners each doing part of a sequential sequence. I'm not surprised you've run into such a pickle

Comment: "would I have to hit space bar 4 times each line? ugh technicalities." - no, you can hit ctrl+k, or click the `{}`, or indent it in your editor. But the indentation is already pretty bonkers as is

Comment: I also believe that `setTimeout(cleanUpStartEntry(), 5000);` won't be doing what you're expecting it to do... You will need to remove the `()` if you want the function to run after 5 seconds; at the moment it'll run the instant that line of code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Truth be told, there are a lot of issues with your code. A massive amount of it is repeated, there are functions that don't do anything, variables that go nowhere, etc. The calculations could be condensed into one-liners, and all the conditionals could be squished down so they only change the bit that's important rather than repeating an entire massive code block. But this isn't https://codereview.stackexchange.com, so I'll stick to the main bug.

The main issue lies in the fact that you're attaching several **asynchronous** event listeners to the click handler. Because they're asynchronous, they could feasibly run in any order they so please. Because of this, certain things that are required by certain functions are not available when they're executed. The simplest way of fixing this is just to make a single event handler and then run the functions in the order you so wish. Really, the code should be better structured and separated out, but the NaN issue is fixed just by consolidating them all.

## Edit:

Just noticed that one big bug is also that two lines of your code are the wrong way around. The oddly named `wooHoo` variable is trying to reference `remainingMinutes` before it's set:

```
var wooHoo = remainingMinutes + bigNoRemainder;
var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
```

But then equally, you could also probably change this:

```
var hundreds3 = startingMinutes / 100;
var noRemainder = Math.floor(hundreds3);
var bigNoRemainder = noRemainder * 60;
var wooHoo = remainingMinutes + bigNoRemainder;
var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
var secondHalf = (remainingMinutes / 100) * 60;
var eleFun = secondHalf + bigNoRemainder
var superMinutes = remainingMinutes / 60;
var whatEvs = secondHalf + sixties;
simActual[i].value = (wooHoo / 60).toFixed(2);
```

... to something a bit sleeker:

```
var bigNoRemainder = Math.floor(startingMinutes / 100) * 60;
var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
simActual[i].value = ((remainingMinutes + bigNoRemainder) / 60).toFixed(2);
```

I also wanted to show how you could take that entire `actualHoursF` function and half the number of lines used whilst still keeping it readable:

```
function actualHoursF() {
  for (var i = 0; i < simActual.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {

      var startingMinutes = simEnd[i].value - simStart[i].value;
      var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
      var noRemainder = Math.floor(startingMinutes / 100);
      var bigNoRemainder = Math.floor(startingMinutes / 100) * 60;
      var totalMinutes = (noRemainder * 60) + remainingMinutes;

      if (startingMinutes < 60) {
        simActual[i].value = (startingMinutes / 60).toFixed(2);
      }
      else if (startingMinutes > 100 && startingMinutes < 130) {
        simActual[i].value = ((remainingMinutes / 60) + noRemainder).toFixed(2);
      }
      else if (startingMinutes > 130) {
        simActual[i].value = ((remainingMinutes + bigNoRemainder) / 60).toFixed(2);
      }
      else {
        simActual[i].value = (totalMinutes / 100).toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Bugfixed code:

I've left most of your code the same except for some formatting and removal of functions that are never called:

```
var workOrderEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".workOrder");
var startTimeEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".startTime");
var endTimeEntry = document.querySelectorAll(".endTime");
var hoursTotal = document.querySelectorAll(".totalHours");
var simStart = document.querySelectorAll(".simStart");
var simEnd = document.querySelectorAll(".simEnd");
var simActual = document.querySelectorAll(".simActual");
var calc = document.querySelector("#calculate");
var moreLines = document.querySelector("#moreLines");
var tableRow = document.querySelector(".row");
var bigTotal = document.querySelector(".bigTotal");
var bigActual = document.querySelector(".bigActual");
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

function totalCalc() {
  var smallTotal = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < hoursTotal.length; i++) {
    var numberU = parseFloat(hoursTotal[i].value, 10);
    if (hoursTotal[i].value != 0) {
      smallTotal += numberU;
      bigTotal.value = smallTotal + " rough hours";
    }
  }
}

function actualCalc() {
  var smallActual = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < simActual.length; i++) {
    var numberW = parseFloat(simActual[i].value, 10);
    if (simActual[i].value != 0) {
      smallActual += numberW;
      bigActual.value = smallActual.toFixed(2) + " actual hours";
    }
  }
}

function newStartTime() {

  for (var i = 0; i < startTimeEntry.length; i++) {
    var randomStart = Math.random();
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {
      if (randomStart > 0.5) {
        if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "3" &&
          startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "1" &&
          startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "4") {
          var randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "3") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "1") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "4") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else randomNum = (Math.random() * 3) - 40;
      }
      else if (randomStart < 0.5) {

        if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "3" &&
          startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "1" &&
          startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "4") {

          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3) - 40;
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "3") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "1") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "4") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else randomNum = (Math.random() * -3) - 40;
      }
      var roundNum = Math.floor(randomNum)
      var numberx = parseInt(startTimeEntry[i].value);
      simStart[i].value = (roundNum + numberx);
      if (simStart[i].value < 1000) {
        simStart[i].value = "0" + (roundNum + numberx);
      }
    }
  }
}

//there is something adding 40 to the starttimeentry
//need to fix tha

function newEndTime() {

  for (var i = 0; i < endTimeEntry.length; i++) {
    var randomStart = Math.random();
    if (endTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {
      if (randomStart > 0.5) {
        if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "3" &&
          endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "1" &&
          endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "4") {
          var randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "3") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "1") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "4") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * 3);
        }
        else randomNum = (Math.random() * 3) - 40;
      }
      else if (randomStart < 0.5) {

        if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "3" &&
          endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "1" &&
          endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) !== "4") {

          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3) - 40;
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "3") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "1") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else if (endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) === "4") {
          randomNum = (Math.random() * -3);
        }
        else randomNum = (Math.random() * -3) - 40;
      }
      var roundNum = Math.floor(randomNum)
      var numberx = parseInt(endTimeEntry[i].value);
      simEnd[i].value = (roundNum + numberx);
      if (simEnd[i].value < 1000) {
        simEnd[i].value = "0" + (roundNum + numberx);
      }
    }
  }
}

function totalHoursF() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hoursTotal.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {
      if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(3) == "5" || startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "3") {
        var numberx = parseInt(startTimeEntry[i].value);
        var wig = numberx + 40;
        if (startTimeEntry[i].value < 1000) {
          startTimeEntry[i].value = "0" + wig;
        }
        else startTimeEntry[i].value = wig;
      }
      var startingMinutes = (endTimeEntry[i].value - startTimeEntry[i].value);
      var hundreds = startingMinutes / 100;
      var noRemainder = Math.floor(hundreds);
      var sixties = noRemainder * 60;
      var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
      var totalMinutes = sixties + remainingMinutes;
      hoursTotal[i].value = totalMinutes / 60;
    }
  }
}

function cleanUpStartEntry() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hoursTotal.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "5" || startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "7" || startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "8") {
      var numberY = startTimeEntry[i].value - 40;
      startTimeEntry[i].value = numberY;
      if (startTimeEntry[i].value < 1000) {
        startTimeEntry[i].value = "0" + numberY;
      }
    }
  }
}

function cleanUpEndEntry() {
  for (var i = 0; i < hoursTotal.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "5" || endTimeEntry[i].value.charAt(2) == "7") {
      var numberY = endTimeEntry[i].value - 40;
      endTimeEntry[i].value = numberY;
      if (endTimeEntry[i].value < 1000) {
        endTimeEntry[i].value = "0" + numberY;
      }
    }
  }
}

function cleanUpSimStart() {
  for (var i = 0; i < simActual.length; i++) {
    if (simStart[i].value.charAt(2) == "8" || simStart[i].value.charAt(2) == "7" || simStart[i].value.charAt(2) == "9" || simStart[i].value.charAt(2) == "6") {
      var numberY = simStart[i].value - 40;
      simStart[i].value = numberY;
      if (simStart[i].value < 1000) {
        simStart[i].value = "0" + numberY;
      }
      //remember need to add startTimeEntry into this too
    }
  }
}

function cleanUpSimEnd() {
  for (var i = 0; i < simActual.length; i++) {
    if (simEnd[i].value.charAt(2) == "8" || simEnd[i].value.charAt(2) == "7" || simEnd[i].value.charAt(2) == "9" || simEnd[i].value.charAt(2) == "6") {
      var numberY = simEnd[i].value - 40;
      simEnd[i].value = numberY;
      if (simEnd[i].value < 1000) {
        simEnd[i].value = "0" + numberY;
      }
    }
  }
}

function actualHoursF() {
  for (var i = 0; i < simActual.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {
      var startingMinutes = (simEnd[i].value - simStart[i].value);
      if (startingMinutes < 60) {
        var hundreds1 = startingMinutes / 60;

        simActual[i].value = (hundreds1).toFixed(2);
      }
      else if (startingMinutes > 100 && startingMinutes < 130) {
        var hundreds2 = startingMinutes / 100;
        var noRemainder = Math.floor(hundreds2);
        var sixties = noRemainder * 60;
        var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
        var secondHalf = (remainingMinutes / 100) * 60;
        var superMinutes = remainingMinutes / 60;
        var percentage = remainingMinutes / 100;
        var extraMinutes = percentage * 60;
        var totalMinutes = sixties + extraMinutes;
        var whatEvs = secondHalf + sixties;
        simActual[i].value = (superMinutes + noRemainder).toFixed(2);
      }
      else if (startingMinutes > 130) {
        var hundreds3 = startingMinutes / 100;
        var noRemainder = Math.floor(hundreds3);
        var bigNoRemainder = noRemainder * 60;
        var wooHoo = remainingMinutes + bigNoRemainder;
        var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
        var secondHalf = (remainingMinutes / 100) * 60;
        var eleFun = secondHalf + bigNoRemainder
        var superMinutes = remainingMinutes / 60;
        var whatEvs = secondHalf + sixties;
        simActual[i].value = (wooHoo / 60).toFixed(2);
      }
      else {
        var hundreds4 = startingMinutes / 100;
        var noRemainder = Math.floor(hundreds4);
        var sixties = noRemainder * 60;
        var remainingMinutes = startingMinutes % 100;
        var totalMinutes = sixties + remainingMinutes;
        var percentage = totalMinutes / 100;
        simActual[i].value = (percentage).toFixed(2);
      }
    }
  }
}

function newSimStart() {
  for (var i = 1; i < simEnd.length; i++) {
    if (startTimeEntry[i].value !== "") {
      simStart[i].value = simEnd[i - 1].value;
    }
  }
}

calc.addEventListener("click", function () {
  totalCalc();
  actualCalc();
  newStartTime();
  newEndTime();
  totalHoursF();
  cleanUpStartEntry();
  cleanUpEndEntry();
  cleanUpSimStart();
  cleanUpSimEnd();
  actualHoursF();
  newSimStart();
});

setTimeout(cleanUpStartEntry, 5000);
setTimeout(cleanUpEndEntry, 5000);
setTimeout(cleanUpSimStart, 5000);
setTimeout(cleanUpSimEnd, 5000);
```

Comment: Hey thanks Matt you are a huge help.  I admit my code is overly complicated and messy, and has many formatting/syntax issues as well as some variables with dumb names. It's the same app that I have been working on for a few months on and off, and I started writing it when I first started coding and I'm still very new and inexperienced at this, but your edits make a lot of sense.  There are even functions at the top of the code that don't do anything or work properly.

Comment: Those are ones that I was trying to get to work just for experimentation purposes (adding additional rows to the table etc)  Before I got your answer, I was able to solve the issue of the order the functions were called but re sequencing them.  I like (and understand) the way you have streamlined a lot of my code.  If I were writing it now, I would try to be more concise with it.

Comment: Another problem I may be having is that I am probably thinking synchronously.  I don't know any other programming languages but I know how to write basic, and CNC GE Fanuc controls and I know some ladder logic programmable logic which is sequential lines maybe that is messing me up too.

Comment: T.J. Crowder - I know I shouldnt have bypassed that message.  It wont happen again, but I'm glad I did only because I was very wrong on my code and needed to hear the constructive criticism on here!  I learned a LOT today seriously!

Comment: OK so I tried taking you guys advice and making one event listener that fires multiple functions (11 total).  I know I'm doing it wrong but not sure how its wrong.

Comment: calc.addEventListener("click",newStartTime,newEndTime,cleanUpStartEntry,cleanUpEndEntry,cleanUpSimStart,cleanUpSimEnd,newSimStart,totalHoursF,actualHoursF,totalCalc,actualCalc); Im sorry I'm new here and tried to give this code 4 spaces each line but wouldn't work

Comment: UPDATE:  I made a funtion that is bound to .calc with one event handler, and that function runs all my other functions in order I specify.  Still getting NaN though.  Need to look into it some more.